# Strange thick line in python plots?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib.pyplot in python. Consider y-axis is real values called "ranking loss" and x-axis is the number of the iterations(1000). Then I plot the average ranking loss of 2 runs of an algorithm in each iteration.

Does anyone know why do I get this strange thick chart instead of a line?

Thank you very much in advance

[image]

And the command is :

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('Batch-GD', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Iteration', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('Avg ranking loss', fontsize=16)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlim(0, iter)
    plt.plot(avg_loss)
    fig.savefig('GD_with_ini.jpg')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you show us your actual plot command?

Comment: @suever I think I have to set the range in y-axis suitably. I added the code on the question.

Comment: Please edit Your question, and include the code there.

Comment: The `avg_loss` might simply be oscillating. What happens if you zoom into the plot. Or what happens if you use `plt.plot(avg_loss, marker=".", c="k", ls="", alpha=0.5)`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Actually the runs take long time, I am trying to see what happens and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening here is probably, that your line density is so high that lines overlap in a way that a plain surface is shown instead of the line itself.

If we take e.g. 10000 points and make the plot oscillate at very high frequency, we get a similar behaviour. Zooming in shows that there actually is a line.

[image]

Code to reproduce the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes, mark_inset

x = np.linspace(0,1000,num=10000)
y = np.sin(x*100.)*x/5000.+np.exp(-x/60.)+np.sin(x/50.)*0.016

plt.plot(x,y)

###### show inset ####
ax = plt.gca()
axins = inset_axes(ax, 2,2, loc=1)
axins.plot(x,y)
axins.set_xlim(400, 410)
axins.set_ylim(-0.1, 0.17)
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")

plt.show()
```

A solution can then be to calculate some kind of rolling average. E.g.:

```
def running_mean(x, N):
    cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(x, 0, 0)) 
    return (cumsum[N:] - cumsum[:-N]) / N 
N=300
cumsum = running_mean(y, N)
ax.plot(x[N//2:-N//2+1], cumsum, c="orange")
axins.plot(x[N//2:-N//2+1], cumsum, c="orange")
```

[image]

Comment: I ran the program once more (using the command in your comment above) and realized the oscillation. Taking this rolling average is perfect. Thank you very much.